# How can I efficiently turn a vector of 1-dim array into a 2-dim array(matrix) in Julia?

Tags: julia

As mentioned I have a vector of 1D matrice, such as:

```
P_predefined = [[.3 .4 .2 .1], [.2 .3 .5 0.], [.1 0. .8 .1], [.4 0. 0. .6]]
```

I would like to turn it into a matrix of 2D, I tried to use vcat, for which I expected to behave like vstack in Python, but it doesn't work.

```
vcat(algorithm.predefinedP)
```

It still returns a vector

```
[[0.3 0.4 0.2 0.1], [0.2 0.3 0.5 0.0], [0.1 0.0 0.8 0.1], [0.4 0.0 0.0 0.6]] #Vector{Matrix{Float64}}
```

How should I do it in the right way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Julia 1.9 has `stack`, which can be used on earlier Julia versions via the package Compat.

```
julia> using Compat

julia> P_predefined = vec.([[.3 .4 .2 .1], [.2 .3 .5 0.], [.1 0. .8 .1], [.4 0. 0. .6]])
4-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]
 [0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.0]
 [0.1, 0.0, 0.8, 0.1]
 [0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6]

julia> stack(P_predefined)
4×4 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.3  0.2  0.1  0.4
 0.4  0.3  0.0  0.0
 0.2  0.5  0.8  0.0
 0.1  0.0  0.1  0.6

julia> stack(P_predefined; dims=1)
4×4 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.3  0.4  0.2  0.1
 0.2  0.3  0.5  0.0
 0.1  0.0  0.8  0.1
 0.4  0.0  0.0  0.6
```

Note: your `P_predefined` is a vector of `1xn` matrices, instead of vectors. I've used `vec` here to convert them to vectors.

Comment: `stack(vec, P_predefined)` is another way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

> `vcat(A...)`
>
> Concatenate along dimension 1. To efficiently concatenate a large
> vector of arrays, use `reduce(vcat, x)`.

```
julia> reduce(vcat, P_predefined)
4×4 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.3  0.4  0.2  0.1
 0.2  0.3  0.5  0.0
 0.1  0.0  0.8  0.1
 0.4  0.0  0.0  0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention efficiency, a comprehension will be 2X faster than `vcat`.

```
m, n = length(P_predefined), length(P_predefined[1])   
@btime mat = [$P_predefined[i][j] for i=1:$m, j=1:$n]
@btime mat = reduce(vcat, $P_predefined)

  # 29.347 ns (1 allocation: 192 bytes)
  # 72.131 ns (1 allocation: 192 bytes)
```